# catch the twitter login from a popupwindow

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twitter, popup, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for google chrome.

I open a little popup window where I want to provide a service, but if the user is not logged into twitter, he has to click on a button where a new window will open with the api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate url..

After he loggs into twitter, the api.twitter.com will redirect to another page and then it has to close itself, and right behind that I want to refresh my popup window so that my service will be open.

it is possible to inject with the manifst.json from my extension a .js file into the api.twitter.com page where I can maybe catch the login and then close the window with JS. 
But I'm not sure how I can see if he is logged in..

You can see a working solution with the popup in the shareoholic twitter extension.. maybe someone is using it.

Thanks and Regards
Martin

Answer (score 2):

I think the proper way of doing this would be implementing OAuth authorization process in your extension. See [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/tut_oauth.html). Twitter OAuth implementation is described [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already have the login process working, what I want is to open the login process in another window, and after the user logges into twitter, the window has to be closed and the mainwindow refreshed